# Missing localization in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, ios-simulator, xcode6

Since update to Xcode 6.1 yesterday there is no correct localization of apps in the iOS Simulator. I switched the language and region to German/Germany and my apps are still in English and only English keyboard is available. Localization was fine in Xcode 6.0.1 and iOS 8.0 Simulator.

Does anybody have similar problems?

[image]

Comment: Did you try it on a device? Also is the simulator language in German before running your app? If yes, try resetting the simulator contents and give it another try.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS8.1 beta1 Simulator always uses US keyboard layout despite german hardware keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146668/ios8-1-beta1-simulator-always-uses-us-keyboard-layout-despite-german-hardware-ke)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possible work around is to set the "Application Language" in the used scheme.

Source: [Answer of Yoshihiro Sakamoto in Apple Dev Forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1062623#1062623)

Comment: This will only work for Build&Run from Xcode and not for "finger launching" but is really the best you'll be able to do for now =/

Comment: what is"finger launching" ?

Comment: "finger launching" means launching an app with your finger over the simulator user interface and not of the build&run button from Xcode

Answer (score 6):

This was mentioned in the [Xcode 6.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-DontLinkElementID_23)

> In some situations, [NSLocale currentLocale] may return en_US instead of the chosen locale in the iOS 8.1 simulator.

Comment: this is the correct answer ! Is there a way we can indicate this on stack overflow ? Had the same problem, works correctly on the device, but not in the simulator.

Answer (score 5):

[image: I just do by above answer AlexVogel]

I just do by above answer AlexVoge. Beginner maybe need a picture :]