# iOS App Localizations Not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xliff

This is getting very frustrating. I've localized my iOS app for French and **none** of the translations are showing up in the app. Localizable.strings, Storyboard.strings, Info.plist.strings -- none of them are working.

I've set the iOS Simulator, Device, and Scheme language to French and still it shows the app in English. The project has `Base Internationalization` turned ON. 4 files are localized for "English - Development Language" and 6 files are localized for French. Localized strings files are in UTF-8 format as well.

Not even Xcode is recognizing the localized strings in the Storyboard preview! Take a look at these two photos which exemplify the problem.

[image]

[image]

Everything is localized! I cannot figure out why the app refuses to display localizations for other languages (note, this is happening with the other languages, not just French).

Another note: I have used Xcode's XLIFF import / export features to handle localizations.... so there shouldn't be any file placement issues. I'll attach a screenshot of the project file structure below anyway:

[image]

**Anyone know why localizations are not working properly here?**

Comment: Can someone explain why this question was down voted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing localization in Xcode 6.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480934/missing-localization-in-xcode-6-1)

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Unfortunately, my issue is not specific to Xcode 6.1 and a simple update to Xcode 6.2 provides no remedy. Additionally, those answers detail solutions which I have already tried and am indeed using. So, no, this is not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

One issue like this (setting the language via Settings in the iOS Simulator) was fixed in the iOS 8.2 simulator runtime.

Setting the language via scheme selection in Xcode.app does not work still as of Xcode 6.2.

Comment: Nope. Still having the issue! Xcode 6.2 and iOS 8.2 still refuse to show the localizations.

Comment: Try selecting the language you want in the Settings app.

Comment: As I said in my question, "I've set the **iOS Simulator**, Device, and Scheme language to French and still it shows the app in English". Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes.  Set the language in the Settings app.