# NSCalendar currentCalendar not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

In my project. I want user changes calendar in my project. if user choose Japanese Calendar, then the date show with Japanese Calendar format in my project. If user choose Gregorian, then the date show with Gregorian Calendar format. So i used the class file as below.

Here is ***myclass.h***

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface util : NSObject

+ (NSString *)getTrimedString:(NSString *)str;

+(NSDate*)convertStringToDate:(NSString*)baseString;
+(NSString*)dateToYMD:(NSDate*)date;
+(NSString*)dateToMDHM:(NSDate*)date;
+(NSString*)dateToYMDHM:(NSDate*)date;

+(NSString*)dateToHM:(NSDate*)date;
+(NSString*)convertStringToMDHM:(NSString*)baseString;

+(UILabel*)createWorkLblWord:(NSString*)baseText;
+(UILabel*)createWorkLblWord:(NSString*)baseText widths:(NSInteger)width fontSize:(NSInteger)size;

+(float)systemVersionFloat;

@end


+(NSString*)dateToYMDHM:(NSDate*)date{
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
```

Here is ***myclass.m***

```
#import "util.h"

@implementation util

+(NSString*)dateToYMDHM:(NSDate*)date{
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];



NSCalendar *usercalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

[formatter setCalendar:usercalendar];

NSLog(@"Current Auto Calendar : %@",[[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] calendarIdentifier]);
NSLog(@"current calendar: %@", [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] calendarIdentifier]);

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd\nH:mm"];
    return [formatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

But the result is only show Gregorian Calendar Date format. Even user choose Japanese Calendar or Buddhist Calendar, my project only show Gregorian Calendar Format Date. How can I solve this?

[image: Here is NSLog Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The solved answer for my question is not Coding error. Its just wrong in Scheme Options. I changed my Application Region to System Region in Xcode Product Menu >> Scheme >> Edit Scheme >> Options Tab. [Mr.Andrew Romanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155948/andrew-romanov) saved me. Thanks a lot Mr.Andrw Romanov

Here is my Scheme Options Screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]` try using identifiers, current Calendar picks the default one

for Gregorian
`[[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];`

for buddhist
`[[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSBuddhistCalendar];

Comment: Yes. But our boss want to use, User preferred calendar. He don't want to set the Calendar to Default like - [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

Comment: Does user change the current calendar in the settings application?

Comment: User change the calendar to Japanese in the phone's settings. In our app we use [NSCalendar currentCalendar] to called the phone's settings Calendar. But the date format only show Gregorian Calendar Format.

As for Example : I choose the Calendar to Japanese in The phone's settings. Then the date in app will show as 0028/11/15 . Another Example : I choose the Calendar to Gregorian in The phone's settings. Then the date in app will show as 2016/11/15.

Answer (score 0):

[currentCalendar](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1533497-cfcalendarcopycurrent?language=objc) it is calendar from current locale, that user can change in the phone's settings.
If  you want to allow to user changes the calendar in the application. You shoud create needed calendar with [calendarWithIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendar/1412400-calendarwithidentifier?language=objc) method.
Also you can subscribe to [NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscurrentlocaledidchangenotification), and update the UI.

All code here:

```
@interface ViewController ()

- (IBAction)printCurrentCalendar:(id)sender;
- (void)localeChangedNotification:(NSNotification*)notification;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(localeChangedNotification:) name:NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark Actions
- (IBAction)printCurrentCalendar:(id)sender
{
    NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSLog(@"calendar from currentCalendar: %@", calendar.calendarIdentifier);

    NSCalendar* localeCalendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:[NSLocale currentLocale].calendarIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"calendar from locale: %@",  localeCalendar.calendarIdentifier);
}


- (void)localeChangedNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"locale changed");
}

@end
```

output:

> CalendarCheck[1289:74644] calendar from currentCalendar: gregorian 
>   CalendarCheck[1289:74644] calendar from locale: gregorian
>   CalendarCheck[1289:74644] locale changed
>   CalendarCheck[1289:74644] calendar from currentCalendar: japanese
>   CalendarCheck[1289:74644] calendar from locale: japanese

Comment: Yes... Yes... When user change the calendar in the phone's settings then the date in our app will show as user preferred calendar date. As for Example : I choose the Calendar to Japanese in The phone's settings. 
Then the date in app will show as 0028/11/15 .
Another  Example : I choose the Calendar to Gregorian in The phone's settings.
Then the date in app will show as 2016/11/15.

That's why we want to use [NSCalendar currentCalendar] or [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar]

Comment: I've written small program to check of this information. All works as I've described.

Comment: I tried as you did too. But what's wrong in my project. Its not working with [NSCalendar currentCalendar]. 

But other mini project works it fine. My project is not completely i did.

 I'm just upgrade for OS Update. But the main coder is from Japan. So i can't find the error of this. 

Can you have any suggestion for that how to set the calendar in Xcode project? 

Please help me. My Schedule date is so close, if i can't finish i will be get down impression. Please Help Me!!! I apologize to you.

Comment: Can you make me a sample small project for me by using with as u said -> NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification ??? Please

Comment: I did this in my project with your code. but its not work. I changed calendar in Japanese Calendar in device settings. But its show Gregorian. :( .. Only this project happen like this. In other project, its work fine.

2016-11-15 14:58:08.516 Imadoko[3192:847509] calendar from currentCalendar: gregorian
2016-11-15 14:58:08.517 Imadoko[3192:847509] calendar from locale: gregorian

Comment: Very strange. Also, NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification is not called.

Comment: May be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480934/missing-localization-in-xcode-6-1/26510914#26510914 can help to you

Comment: Thanks alot man.. I got it.. Its work. Your link is worked. I changed my Application Region to System Region in Edit Scheme. Finally No coding error. I Love You Man... Its real. You saved my life.